# How to get layer ID from existing google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to toggle layers of an existing map created on maps.google.com with google V3 API.

To toggle (display / hide) the layer I'm using .setMap function with map/null as argument.

My problem is that I've not found a way to get the list of the existing layers. So I've hardcoded the values in mapLayerNames, but I would have prefer to get them from 'map' variable. Which API am I missing from the doc?

here comes my code: lid are the layer Ids I'm looking for in the url...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KML Layers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>


var mapLayerNames = [
    "http://www.google.com/maps/d/u/1/kml?mid=z_wfVyI764I4.kPvsE6js2GAg&lid=z_wfVyI764I4.kIQKW-gOFhmU",
    "http://www.google.com/maps/d/u/1/kml?mid=z_wfVyI764I4.kPvsE6js2GAg&lid=z_wfVyI764I4.k2u4vYNOkUIA",
    "http://www.google.com/maps/d/u/1/kml?mid=z_wfVyI764I4.kPvsE6js2GAg&lid=z_wfVyI764I4.kcPBYmgvyhbI"
    ];

var map;
var ctaLayer = [];

function initialize() {
  var paris = new google.maps.LatLng(43.5742118,1.4538968);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: paris
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  for (var i=0; i<mapLayerNames.length; i++) {

    ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: mapLayerNames[i]
    });
    ctaLayer.setMap(map);
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you creating the layers? They aren't available from the `map` variable. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code..

Comment: question updated with code example based on google template